# Button obscured by another Button can't be pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

There are 2 buttons - `Button A` and `Button B`.
`Button B` is situated on top of `Button A`.
`Button B` has it's `Button` Component removed.

I want the user to be able to click on `Button A` even though `Button B` obscures it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure What is your question but if you want to click start button while air button is above it. you should disable the option on button called Interactable and also uncheck the toggle in image component of that button called Raycast Target. and that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `Button B` button will block the one underneath it. Because `Image` component and `Text` and/or other `Image` component that button has blocks raycast to the button underneath of it.

You can do one of the following:

- Remove your `Button B` button, because if it's not doing anything and actually interferes with a behavior you want then why have it in the first place? Think about it
- Uncheck `Raycast Target` in your `Button B` button's `Image` component
- Disable `Image` component of `Button B` button altogether

Thinking about first item on the list will benefit you greatly.

If you want a solution then use second or third option on the list, but bare in mind that unchecking `Raycast Target` or disabling `Image` component of your "Air" button still leaves an `Image` and/or `Text` as a child of aforementioned button that CAN and WILL block raycast to your `Button A` button.